# How long does it currently take to get a new biometric Israeli passport if you visit Israel in person?

Tags: passport, israel

Since July 1st Israel will [only issue biometric passports](https://www.gov.il/en/service/application_for_biometric_passport2) within Israel. And as far as I understand consulates are not equipped with biometric scanners, so from now on [they will only issue 5 year regular passports](http://embassies.gov.il/wellington/ConsularServices/Pages/Passports-Travel%20Documents.aspx).

So I'm thinking of flying to Israel in person instead and getting a passport in person there. How long would it currently take me to sort things out there?

Answer (score 1):

The Population and Immigration Authority (רשות האוכלוסין וההגירה) [guarantees](https://www.gov.il/he/Departments/General/questions_and_answer_for_biometric_documents) delivery of your new passport within 10 working days by registered mail, which is the same as before the switch to mandatory biometric passports. However, since these passports undergo a more involved manufacturing process - not at local PIA officers - you can't get them by visiting your local PIA office again a day or two later, like you may have been used to do.

Pity about this further invasion of privacy though.

Comment: Before the biometric passports were introduced you could get it in 2 days if you were okay with two in-person visits. So now I'm wondering if the same procedure is still in use.

Comment: @JonathanReez: See edit.

Comment: Oh well. I guess I'd just wait until their consulates have biometric scanners or get a 5 year passport.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Get the 5-year one. Who knows - maybe Jehova will be merciful and the biometric law is repealed during the next 5 years...

Comment: My biggest concern is that things will go in the opposite direction and biometrics will start becoming mandatory in many countries.

Comment: They already effectively take biometrics in airports, do you think they don't store that? I would guess that they do.

Comment: Yes but for now biometric passports are not mandatory. I'm afraid in the future you won't be able to go anywhere without one.